# How to add html i tag with next and previous button in react-pagination package

Tags: reactjs

Here is my code :

> ```
>                          <ReactPaginate
>                             previousLabel={'Previous'}
>                             nextLabel={'Next'}
>                             breakLabel={"..."}
>                             breakClassName={"break-me"}
>                             pageCount={this.state.pageCount}
>                             marginPagesDisplayed={2}
>                             pageRangeDisplayed={5}
>                             onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
>                             containerClassName={"pagination"}
>                             pageClassName={'page-item'}
>                             subContainerClassName={"page-item"}
>                             activeClassName={"active"}
>                             pageLinkClassName={'page-link'}
>                         />
> ```

I want to add html i tag  with **previousLabel** and with **nextlabel**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nextLabel` accepts a `node`.

[image]

So you can use jsx within the curly bracket.

```
nextLabel={<i your icon node here />}
```

or using image (example)

```
nextLabel={<img src={image url} />}
```

or icon with Text

```
previousLabel={<div><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true" />Previous</div>}
```

Comment: can we use text with it ,like 
 previousLabel={<i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>+"Previous"}

Comment: you need to wrap it, per jsx rules. see updated answer